# How to install / update package with pipenv without updating the rest of packages?

Tags: python, dependency-management, pipenv

With `pipenv`, how do I add or update only one package without changing versions of other packages?  I've tried both:

```
pipenv update --selective-upgrade requests
```

and

```
pipenv update --keep-outdated requests
```

but still versions of all the packages are updated during locking.

Pipfile & Pifile.lock:
https://gist.github.com/jozo/d8351ed708e84c5ea0f69e82e585e5c6

Comment: I think `pipenv update --keep-outdated <pkg>`will work for you [Issue GitHub](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/2665#issuecomment-426656712)

Comment: No, it doesn't work @Maxime - everything is updated.

Comment: According to the discussion in this [Github Issue](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/966) this isn't possible for now.

Answer (score 58):

Running `pipenv install/uninstall/update` with `--keep-outdated` will prevent `pipenv` from updating unrelated locked packages. (It's odd that this is not the default befavior).

If you don't want some packages to ever be updated automatically, you should pin those in your `Pipfile`, e.g:

```
[packages]
django = "==2.2"
djangorestframework = "==3.9.2"
```

Comment: `--keep-outdated` doesn't give me an error but it's still updating everything in the pipfile, for me.

Comment: @Yokhen: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example (perhaps, in a different question). At the time of writing `--keep-outdated` worked as intended for me.

Comment: @EugeneYarmash `keep-outdated` does not work for specific package as reported in this [issue](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/2665#issuecomment-426656712). It seems there is no solution at this time.

Comment: For me, `pipenv unistall --keep-outdated foobar` removed `foobar` from `Pipfile` but not from `Pipfile.lock`

Comment: How do I update the pinned packages via pipenv ?

Comment: @WaqarAli Update the version of the package in `Pipfile` and run `pipenv update <pkg>`.

Comment: For me it worked with --ignore-pipfile :  pipenv install --ignore-pipfile --keep-outdated

Comment: For latest versions, the flag `--keep-outdated` has been removed. One should use `pipenv upgrade` to selectively upgrade packages.

Answer (score 3):

I am using pipenv version 2023.3.20 and according to the documentation it seems the `upgrade` command does it.

For example, to downgrade flake8 to <6 in the dev packages, I ran `pipenv upgrade --dev "flake8<6"`, and it only affected flake8 in the Pipfile.lock, pinning to version `5.0.4`.

Comment: I guess if `install` is already taken, `upgrade` makes sense? I would've chosen `add` instead ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Well, on my comment I just mentioned a way to address the particular problem. I haven't used `pipenv` that much, but so far and used already tools like `Poetry`, I found some commands behaviour a bit confusing to be honest.